# What is this house plant (looks a bit like rocket salad, but succulent)?

Tags: identification, indoors, succulents

I got this plant from a colleague couple of years ago and she said she didn't know how it was called, supposedly "stag horns" or something, but it's definitely not stag horn fern.

It can grow really large, and quickly: a bit I gave away for the office grew the height of the window on the sill of which it is placed: all within a year.

This is a really great and low maintenance plant and i give away cuttings to friends, so it would to know what it is... Searched for succulents and descriptions in google but nothing came out.

[[[image: ![htt]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lkqu9.jpg)ps://imgur.com/6aAgyjl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boko7.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Boko7.jpg)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image: Kalanchoe synsepala dissecta][image: Kalanchoe synsepala dissecta]

Kalanchoe synsepala dissecta

Your plant looks very very healthy.  Have you fertilized this plant ever?  What soil are you using in the pot?  Small pots, shallower than tall, clay, are the best.  The only soil you should use is sterilized potting soil, for cactus and succulents or just all purpose.  No garden soil.  Shallow watering and infrequent.  A little bit of Osmocote all purpose extended release fertilizer, a balanced fertilizer, added once per YEAR at half the amount in the directions. Lucky friends.  I would get a bunch of tiny clay pots and get starts started to give away with instructions.  Sweet gift!

Comment: Soooo, what is the plant called?

Comment: That looks like a very mangy stags horn fern, which is NOT what the OP's pictures are. And the cultivation instructions are completely wrong, if stormy thinks it IS a stags horn fern. (For a start, it would be more natural to have it not growing in any soil at all!)

Comment: Google-searched stormy's  image and it's only available at a Japanese website for selling plants, where it's listed as Kalanchoe synsepala (but it does not look like one). Anyway, my plant is in a clay pot although it does not make any difference: it grows in any pot and any soil, practically got a forest from a single branch a colleague of mine pruned from her plant several years ago. It grows well regardless of watering routine - quicker when the water is more.

Comment: I thought stags horn too, but that is not what this is.  I think this is a form of Kalanchoe.  I'll go find a better picture?

Comment: My link was shown but no label...that was there!  Sorry.

Comment: Yes! The first picture is it: Kalanchoe Laciniata - it appears again in a Japanese gardening site, but with the correct label. The second picture is something else, I think. This link: https://worldofsucculents.com/kalanchoe-laciniata-christmas-tree-plant/ shows it clearly. Also, I did use it as a "Christmas tree" last year, before it branched :D

Comment: I like the species name...laciniata.  Yay!  Get those cute little clay pots, tie raffia around it in a bow, make a little card for info and care!  Too much fun!